# How to append file from html-loader to a dom through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, webpack

My front end app is using jquery and managed by webpack. I have a requirement to load additional HTML files at runtime so I use `html-loader` to load the HTML files. I configured `html-laoder` plugin in webpack config file as below:

```
{
                  test: /\.html$/,
                  use: {
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    options: {
                      attrs: false
                    }
                  }
                }
```

In my javascript file I use below code to load the HTML files:

```
const others = require('html-loader!./other.html')
```

the value of `others` is a string of `module.exports = "<div id=\"rightside-sub-bar\">this is properties</div>";`. I can't append the `others` to a dom in jquery like: `$(.my-dom).append(others)`. Instead, I have to put `others` in `eval` like below code:

```
$(.my-dom).append(eval(others))
```

I don't like the way of using `eval` in my js code. What is the better way to load additional HTML files?

Comment: What about minify html files via gulp/grunt and then only use $.load?

Comment: That may be a solution but I want to use webpack and don't want to introduce other tools like gulp/grunt. And by using html-loader, it supports hot reload. It is really handy during developing.

Comment: Okay. So did you try import? Like `import others from 'html-loader!./other.html'` or there is also [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader)..

Comment: I have tried `import` which doesn't work. But I have not tried `raw-loader`. I will have a go for `raw-loader`.